# Ошибка при запуске программы через загрузчик

Tags: c#

Всем привет.

Я решил сделать для программы загрузчик, который проверяет версию, если надо скачивает и *сам закрывается и открывает именно саму программу*. У меня есть код в загрузчике

```
if (version != Launcher.version)
{
    DownloadNewVersion();
}
else
{
    Application.Exit();

    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = @"data\NiceSufring.exe";
    process.Start();
}
```

Программа должна запустить программу по адресу `data\NiceSufring.exe`, и она запускает, при запуске программы идёт чтение из файла `data\system\system.fat`, но беда в том, что если запускать программу через загрузчик, то компилятор выдает ошибку

> Could not find a part of the path

А если запустить программу без загрузчика, а просто сам .exe, то такой ошибки нету и всё работает нормально, скажите из-за чего это может быть? Уже 2 дня бьюсь, никак не пойму, в чём дело.

Comment: Я ответа не знаю на Ваш вопрос, но у меня возник вопрос к Вашему коду, почему условие if (version != Launcher.version) такое, а не ">" ?

Comment: NiceSu**fr**ing.exe до боли напоминает svcho**ts**.exe

Comment: Я знаю что есть ошибка, потом исправлю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Покажите кусок кода который работает с `data\system\system.fat` в `NiceSufring.exe`, а именно как вы получаете путь к `system.fat`.

Если я правильно понял вашу струтуру файлов и папок то скорее всего у вас следующая ошибка:

В файле `NiceSufring.exe` путь к `system.fat` прописан как `system\system.fat`. Это относительный путь, к нему добавляется имя текущего рабочего каталога и поэтому при непосредственном запуске всё нормально открывается. Но при запуске через `Process` рабочий каталог унаследуется от запускающего процесса, а поскольку в корневом каталоге программы нет `system\system.fat`, программа вылетает. Поэтому вам нужно явно установить правильный рабочий каталог для `NiceSufring.exe`.

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "data";
process.StartInfo.FileName = "NiceSufring.exe";
process.Start();
```

Или переделать `NiceSufring.exe` таким образом, чтобы программа при открытии искала `system\system.fat` не в рабочем каталоге, а в каталоге со своим исполняемым файлом.

```
string correctcwd = new FileInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).DirectoryName;
string filename = correctcwd + @"\system\system.fat";
```

Comment: Вот спасибо... всё заработало! :)